# Symfony and Omines DataTable component

Tags: symfony, datatable

I have the following issue:

```
->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, [
    'entity' => Systems::class,
    'query' => function (QueryBuilder $builder) {
    $builder
    ->select('systems')
    ->from(Systems::class, 'systems')
    ->orderBy('systems.level', 'ASC')
    ->addorderBy('systems.label', 'ASC')
    ->andwhere('systems.territory = :SearchTerritory')
    ->setParameter('SearchTerritory', 'Independent');
    },
```

The code as this is working but when I than replace 'Independent' by a variable $territory as example it doesn't work and the message is that the variable isn't declared. Dumping the variable before creating the datatable shows me that the variable is set correctly so somehow the global controller variable isn't send to the datatable and I can't figure out how to that.

Here is the full code:

```
public function territoryList($territory, Environment $twig, Request $request)
{

    $table = $this->createDataTable()
    ->add('label', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Name'])
    ->add('level', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Level'])
    ->add('coordinates', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Coordinates'])
    ->add('territory', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Territory'])
    ->add('missions', BoolColumn::class, ['label' => 'M', 'searchable' => false, 'trueValue' => '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>', 'falseValue' => '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>'])
    ->add('parsteel', BoolColumn::class, ['label' => 'PS', 'searchable' => false, 'trueValue' => '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>', 'falseValue' => '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>'])
    ->add('tritanium', BoolColumn::class, ['label' => 'TT', 'searchable' => false, 'trueValue' => '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>', 'falseValue' => '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>'])
    ->add('dilithium', BoolColumn::class, ['label' => 'DL', 'searchable' => false, 'trueValue' => '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>', 'falseValue' => '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>'])
    ->add('rawgas', BoolColumn::class, ['label' => 'RG', 'searchable' => false, 'trueValue' => '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>', 'falseValue' => '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>'])
    ->add('rawcrystal', BoolColumn::class, ['label' => 'RC', 'searchable' => false, 'trueValue' => '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>', 'falseValue' => '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>'])
    ->add('rawore', BoolColumn::class, ['label' => 'RO', 'searchable' => false, 'trueValue' => '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>', 'falseValue' => '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>'])

    ->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, [
        'entity' => Systems::class,
        'query' => function (QueryBuilder $builder) {
        $builder
        ->select('systems')
        ->from(Systems::class, 'systems')
        ->orderBy('systems.level', 'ASC')
        ->addorderBy('systems.label', 'ASC')
        ->andwhere('systems.territory = :SearchTerritory')
        ->setParameter('SearchTerritory', 'Independent');
        },


        ])
        ->handleRequest($request);

        if ($table->isCallback()) {
            return $table->getResponse();
        }
```

without the twig render etc

Answer (score 1):

In PHP anonymous functions, like the callback provided as the `query` parameter, are privately scoped and do not have access to the outside variables implicitly. See [the section about inheriting variables from the parent scope](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in the PHP documentation for reference.

To import the `$territories` variable you would have to `use` it, ie.

```
'query' => function (QueryBuilder $builder) use ($territories) { ...
```